# Export component with and without hoc in one export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to export component(s) with or without hoc in one export? I know I can do it like this:

```
export const TranslatedList = translate('components')(List);
export const PureList = List;
```

but is there any other way to do something like below:

```
export {
  TranslatedList: translate('components')(List),
  PureList: List,
};
```

and in index.js something like:

```
import { TranslatedList } from './List';

export default TranslatedList;
```

maybe stupid question but this will be really helpful to me

Comment: Yes... why not? Did you try it?

Comment: Ofc I tried, got Cannot resolve symbol TranslatedList and unresolved variable PureList. So it's why I asked :) 1st example works ofc

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use node.js native exports like this:

```
module.exports = {
     TranslatedList: translate('components')(List),
     PureList: List, 
 };
```

And require it

```
const {TranslatedList, PureList} = require('list.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party. I did not find a "great" solution to this issue, but this is an "ok" one, in my opinion.

```
const TranslatedDropzone = translate()(Dropzone)
const TranslatedDropzoneControls = translate()(DropzoneControls)
const TranslatedDropzonePreview = translate()(DropzonePreview)
const TranslatedFilePreview = translate()(FilePreview)

export {
  TranslatedDropzone as Dropzone,
  TranslatedDropzoneControls as DropzoneControls,
  TranslatedDropzonePreview as DropzonePreview,
  TranslatedFilePreview as FilePreview
}

export default TranslatedDropzone
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you simply cannot do this:

```
export {
  TranslatedList: translate('components')(List),
  PureList: List,
};
```

Instead you can try doing this:

```
const toExport = {
      TranslatedList: translate('components')(List),
      PureList: List,
    };

export toExport;
```

To import, simply do this:

```
import { TranslatedList, PureList } from './list.js';
```

Comment: This example did not work for me, got the following error


    Syntax error: ...Component.jsx: Unexpected token, expected { (307:7)
    > 307 | export toExport
          |        ^